# Check EXIF orientation

Tags: images, software-recommendation, photo-editing, workflow, photography

When you create a photo with your camera, the image stores the camera orientation.

(https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html)

I'm trying to find an app that will show these flags.

There are many articles about the apps that can rotate images for you, according to these flags, but I need to simply see them.

I already tried Adobe Bridge CS6, IrfanView and Exif Pilot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bridge CS6 does read this info and includes a filter for image orientation. Do a right click in the 'Filters' panel to see that menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could check the image orientation in Windows by right clicking an image file, select Properties, and open the Details tab. Not sure if you're using a Mac but I would suspect there will be something similar.

The Dimensions property will show the horizontal side (on the left) and the vertical side (on the right). So, if the horizontal size is the biggest size, then the orientation must be landscape. If the vertical size is the biggest, then the orientation must be portrait.

I checked this with two CR2 RAW files from a Canon mirrorless camera that records the orientation when shooting, for both a landscape and portrait photograph. I didn't rotate either of these images manually. The OS picked up which way to rotate when I transferred the RAW images to my computer.

[image]

Obviously I also have a codec installed for Windows that displays the CR2 Thumbnails in Explorer (can't remember which one I installed), so I can see the orientation anyway. Perhaps that is one route you could go down.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (3Apr23) looking at the .jpg file properties in windows10 doesn't help, as windows10 will have already read the "Exif.Image.Orientation" info and auto-rotated the image if necessary, and adjusts the "width" and "height" settings to reflect what it is displaying.

Ps.  If I suspect but am not sure if an image has "Exif.Image.Orientation" set, then I open the .jpg in "Microsoft Paint" and then just re-save it, as Paint will resave the image in the correct/viewed orientation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/114964)